# How to validate Twiter Id's URL to know their current status

Tags: excel, vba, twitter

I have just download the Twiter ID's URL to know their status either, the id's are still `active`, `blocked`, `suspended`, or `deleted`. I am using the following VBA Code but it does not work as I mentioned above.

```
Public PageSource As String
Public PageSourceOpt As Integer
Public httpRequest As Object

Function GetURLRedirect(ByVal Cell As Range, Optional AllowRedirects As Boolean)
    Const WinHttpRequestOption_EnableRedirects = 6
    Dim URL As String
    URL = Cell.Text
    If httpRequest Is Nothing Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Set httpRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
        If httpRequest Is Nothing Then
            Set httpRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5")
        End If
        Err.Clear
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
    ' Control if the URL being queried is allowed to redirect.
    httpRequest.Option(WinHttpRequestOption_EnableRedirects) = AllowRedirects
    ' Clear any pervious web page source information
    PageSource = ""
    ' Add protocol if missing
    If InStr(1, URL, "://") = 0 Then
        URL = "http://" & URL
    End If
    ' Launch the HTTP httpRequest synchronously
    On Error Resume Next
    httpRequest.Open "GET", URL, False
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        ' Handle connection errors
        Cell.Offset(0, 1) = Err.Description
        Err.Clear
        Exit Function
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    ' Send the http httpRequest for server status
    On Error Resume Next
    httpRequest.Send
    httpRequest.WaitForResponse
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        ' Handle server errors
        PageSource = "Error"
        Cell.Offset(0, 1) = Err.Description
        Err.Clear
    Else
        ' Show HTTP response info
        Cell.Offset(0, 1) = httpRequest.Status & " - " & httpRequest.StatusText
        If httpRequest.Status > 300 And httpRequest.Status < 400 Then
            Cell.Offset(0, 2) = httpRequest.GetResponseHeader("Location")
        End If
        ' Save the web page text
        If PageSourceOpt <> 0 Then
            PageSource = httpRequest.ResponseText
            Cell.Offset(0, 3) = PageSource
            Cell.Offset(0, 3).ClearFormats
        End If
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Sub ValidateURLs()
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim RngEnd As Range
    Dim Status As String
    Dim Wks As Worksheet
    Set Wks = ActiveSheet
    Set Rng = Wks.Range(TextBox1.Text)
    Set RngEnd = Wks.Cells(Rows.Count, Rng.Column).End(xlUp)
    If RngEnd.Row < Rng.Row Then Exit Sub Else Set Rng = Wks.Range(Rng, RngEnd)
    Cells(3, 5) = RngEnd.Row - 2
    For Each Cell In Rng
        GetURLRedirect Cell
        DoEvents
        Cells(5, 5) = Cell.Row - 2
    Next Cell
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    PageSourceOpt = CheckBox1.Value
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ValidateURLs
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    TextBox1.Text = ActiveCell.Address
End Sub
```

This code does not validate the URLs and replies as `Bad Request`. The output is as under.
[image]

The sample ids are as under.

```
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/728384693255602176.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/728384180082479104.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/728382362610868228.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/728337281749110784.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/728329768693731328.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/728114035770597377.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/728055476353519616.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/727989216852869121.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/727694698299564033.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/727679014454747136.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/727633679300747264.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/727632901416714240.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/727273627729567744.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/727247264616341508.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/727084719641268224.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/726896995084836864.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/726540699231875073.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/726206873746034688.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/725886004574351363.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/725841017534963712.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/725804881869570048.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/725803040050020353.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/725671578822807556.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/725657863989784576.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/725657863989780480.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/725233500169719808.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/725164262893584389.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/724729328026558464.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/724384631286419456.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/723647669625737216.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/723645534729175041.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/723271156623499264.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/723056630829477888.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/722902550438019072.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/722549303340740608.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/722544334642356225.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/722297007256154112.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/722237965745848320.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/1350293980911607811.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/1350213537965117440.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/1350210436168204289.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/1349963632210182145.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/1349930349627801600.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/1349916656609316871.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/1349901209054838785.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/1349900058196541442.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/1349864288127598592.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/1349849317821988865.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/1349848716761460737.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/1349830160707534850.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/1349829937478320129.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/1349693266359324673.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/1349691888094220295.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/1349685869771333632.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/1349490785373229057.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/1349487954113093632.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/1349474349149954049.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/1349333840553152517.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/1349323821929484290.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/1349233656926064641.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/1348909750948282370.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/1348893075855183875.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/1348837433303986177.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/1348782225618137090.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/1348758112480546816.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/1348748262371561472.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/1348582349454204931.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/1348578956417503232.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/1348570633102188544.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/1348538375788060675.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/1348535908576894976.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/1348532398632275970.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/1348527916167032834.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/1348523333776601088.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/1348415822176292865.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/1348071704547840003.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/1348053707015901187.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/1194511912790151173.html
https://twitter.com/Adam_Creighton/status/1142998150505828353.html
```

Please guide me where the code is not working well. I want four types of status.

1. Active
2. Suspended
3. Deleted
4. Blocked

I hope this makes sense. Thanks

Comment: Did you write this code or downloaded it from somewhere?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Yes I found it online, and I am working to validate my friends list .

Answer (score 2):

I did a quick test of the URL with [Postman](https://www.postman.com) and it seems to be that Twitter checks the user agent of the browser. So since Postman uses by default `User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.26.8` Twitter responds with a `400 Bad Request` and *"This browser is no longer supported."*.

The exact same happens when you set no user agent (as you did in your VBA).

Now you could add a fake user agent like `User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)` to your headers. Then you get a `200 OK` and Twitter responds *"JavaScript is deactivated in your browser"*.

So probably that is still not what you want (and I don't know how to trick Twitter here), but actually you at least now know what's going on there.

I recommend to test and built your requests with a tool like Postman because it is much easier to investigate the responses.

So actually the code is working correctly, but the issue is how Twitter handles your request. Since it obviously checks for a running JavaScript this will only work in a browser.

The correct solution to this problem would probably be to use the offical API that Twitter provides.